# Do extensions have to be installed on VS Code server when using remote tunnelling?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, tunneling

I have recently attempted to set up tunnelling using vs codes' built-in extension. I read that when using the tunnel some extensions will run locally and some will run on the remote machine. Both machines that I am tunnelling between have exactly the same extensions but when tunnelling from one to the other some extensions have a caution message saying:

"This extension is disabled in this workspace because it is defined to run in the Remote Extension Host."

Despite already having these extensions downloaded. So does the vs code server running on my machine have to have these extensions installed on it; or am I neglecting to configure my existing extensions appropriately?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!